# UIScrollView won't scroll to reveal more content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I've been working on this for the past couple of hours and can't figure this out.

I have a scrollview with content added to it as a subview, but my scroll view won't scroll past the tabBarController, even though the content goes beyond this point.

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
self.scrollView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
```

I figured this would work, but definitely doesn't. I've been searching for an answer and can't find one, help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If your scrollviews frame and contentSize are the same height, it won't be able to scroll, the contentSize should be higher than your scrollview frame in order to make the scrollerview be able to scroll.

Comment: This is true, if I set the contentSize to 1000 and keep the frame at 560 it will scroll, but it also shows a ton of white space after my content. I guess my question is, how do I get the scroll view to automatically adjust how much scroll is needed based on how much content there is?

Comment: Well that depends in your content, you should be able to calculate your scrollers size based on what are you adding to it

Answer (score 1):

[JonLOo’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28517495/2207249) covers the original question. To address your new question:

> How do I get the scroll view to automatically adjust how much scroll is needed based on how much content there is?

Read through Apple’s [Technical Note TN2154:
UIScrollView And Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html), particularly the *Pure Auto Layout Approach* section. Essentially, the constraints on the content views must fully specify a size, which the scroll view uses as its content size.

Answer (score 0):

On method: `viewDidLoad` you will get different height of your scrollView. Try to get on `viewDidAppear`

Try also:
`scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;`

Comment: I just tried putting it in viewDidAppear, but I get the same result, it doesn't scroll passed the tabBarController.

Comment: Ok, which is the height of view? If is the height of screen,then this will not work.

Comment: Try to put a great height. Like 2000.